# Visualize number of failed or timed out queries in Redshift using Cloudwatch

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to visualize number of failed or timed out queries in Redshift using Cloudwatch.
Wondering if there is any Cloudwatch metrics in Redshift to measure failed or timed out queries?
One solution that I thought is to implement a Lambda function to query STL_QUERY where aborted =1 and send the result to Cloudwatch, any other though or recommendation?

Comment: That's how I've done similar things for clients in the past.